# CAN bus PIDs for SEAT

Tags: ac, can-bus, seat, seat-ibiza, pid

I have a project in my university. I'm trying to recognize the driver using the data from the car.
I'm using Raspberry Pi with PiCAN (CAN Bus).
car: SEAT Ibiza 2017
I'm looking for more PIDs (not the regular ones), for example, I'm looking for PID that show if the A/C is on/off, or Turn signals.
where can I find those PIDs?